# How to replace more than one character without entering insert mode?

Tags: replace, repeated-commands

I have a file with a line that looks like this:

```
foofoo.xy.barbar
```

I want to change the `xy` to `gh`. I tried to do <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> -> <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>, but obviously that didn't work, as it replaced the `xy` with `gg` and then moved my cursor one spot to the left.

Is there a way to do this without entering insert mode, or without using a lot more keystrokes (e.g. <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>)?

Comment: `R` enters Replace Mode. `:help replace-mode` for more information.

Comment: I tried `vt.rgh`. But the result was the same as yours except for the cursor position.

Comment: Why don't you want to enter insert mode? Something like `cwgh<esc>` would work fine.

Comment: @durron597 I'm not sure if `minimize-keystrokes` is a good tag, it's usually not really what the question is *about*, as such. (I rejected your proposed edits) ... Perhaps you should discuss at meta?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If the new text is the same length as the old text, Vim's **replace mode** is an option. From normal mode, <kbd>R</kbd> (that's a capital "r") brings you into replace mode. This is similar to "overwrite" in some other text editors: instead of inserting new characters like in insert mode, typing will replace the character under the cursor, and then advance to the next cursor. (Think of it like the lower-case `r`, but for more than just a single character at a time.) Find the documentation for replace mode with [`:help replace-mode`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#mode-replace).

In your case: with the cursor between the `.` and the `x`, get in to replace mode by pressing <kbd>R</kbd>. Now when you type <kbd>g</kbd> it replaces the "x" and moves to the next character, so you can type <kbd>h</kbd> to replace the "y". Your edit is done now, so <kbd>Escape</kbd> to return to to normal mode.

(This works when your replacement text is the same length as the old text, but if your replacement is longer or shorter, `c` might be all you need: it will replace<sup>1</sup> the text within a movement, with the text you then type. There are many ways to do use `c`, for example: with the cursor between the `.` and `x`, <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>`ABC`<kbd>Escape</kbd> says to **c**hange the text (up '**t**il the next ***`.`***) with "ABC".)

---

<sup>1</sup> It'll yank the text in the movement into [the unnamed/`"` register](http://usevim.com/2012/04/13/registers/) and then switch into insert mode, so that you can type something to replace it, and then <kbd>Escape</kbd> back to normal mode.

Comment: This works for this case. What if you wanted to replace those 2 chars by say 3 chars?

Comment: Good question; amended to include a way to handle different length text.

Comment: Yeah, I know that way. But that way you enter Insert mode and I was curious to see if there was a way not to use Insert mode in that case. Not that I think it very useful (and yet I could be wrong).

Comment: Prefix with a numeral `n` to replace up to the `n`-th occurence of the target character. This is useful for replacing parts of labels with the format `w_x_y_z` and `a-b-c-d`. Use `f` instead of `t` to remove the limiting character as well.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple ways you could do this, but the simplest I can think of is:

### TL;DR

`fxcw<REPLACEMENT TEXT>`

### Explanation

- `fx` jumps you to the x (see [`help *f*`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#f))
- `cw` says to change the word (see [`:h *c*`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#c), [`:help *w*`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#w), and [`:help cw`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#cw) for more information), removing the "xy" text and entering insert mode, letting you put whatever you want right there.
- < REPLACEMENT TEXT > is whatever you want to replace it with - "gh" in your example.

One advantage of this approach is that it uses very commonly used text manipulation & navigation commands. Another is that "xy" could be of any length, and this would still work.

The `cw` works because your text object is surrounded by periods (`.`), which act as a boundary to the word.

If your cursor is already on the  "y" character (or any character in the text to be replaced), you could use `ciw<REPLACEMENT TEXT>`. This tells vim to change the word you're in, even if you're not at the beginning of it. See [`:help text-objects`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#text-objects) for more information on `ciw` and text objects in general.

Comment: won't this place him in insert mode?

Comment: Ah - didn't catch that part of his question. In that case, yes - R is the most appropriate solution.

Answer (score 3):

Replace mode:

```
Rgh<Esc>
```

is the most obvious solution if the replacement is the same length as the original but you could also do:

```
2sgh<Esc>
```

or:

```
cegh<Esc>
```

Answer (score 1):

`:1,$s/xy/gh/g` has worked for me since 1987. I interpret it to mean "From line 1 to the end ($) s-search for xy, replace with gh, do it in this 'space'.

Comment: Welcome to Vi and Vim SE and thank you for posting an answer. Any reason for not using `:%s` to operate on the whole buffer and save two keystrokes? That adds up to a lot if used frequently over the course of 36 years :-)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! No need to "interpret": the substitute command is documented by `:help :substitute` in Vim and by the POSIX spec for Vi.